# How can I spread a data frame (from long to wide) and preserve two fields' data?

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I have a data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 
17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 
17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 
17563, 17563, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 
17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 
17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17565, 
17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 
17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 
17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 
17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 
17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 
17566, 17566), class = "Date"), hour = c("00", "01", "02", "03", 
"04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "00", "01", 
"02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "23", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
"09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23"), offered = c(30L, 28L, 15L, 21L, 11L, 
14L, 18L, 35L, 42L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 54L, 45L, 37L, 52L, 40L, 66L, 
84L, 69L, 75L, 51L, 39L, 38L, 25L, 21L, 18L, 20L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 
28L, 37L, 50L, 46L, 31L, 45L, 45L, 39L, 31L, 48L, 69L, 91L, 117L, 
74L, 66L, 60L, 37L, 20L, 31L, 15L, 26L, 18L, 12L, 21L, 42L, 107L, 
118L, 138L, 137L, 93L, 109L, 102L, 91L, 102L, 76L, 76L, 70L, 
68L, 74L, 55L, 54L, 28L, 19L, 23L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 18L, 39L, 96L, 
119L, 111L, 95L, 65L, 81L, 67L, 76L, 64L, 64L, 68L, 71L, 54L, 
65L, 51L, 41L), answered = c(30L, 28L, 15L, 21L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 
35L, 42L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 54L, 45L, 37L, 51L, 40L, 66L, 83L, 68L, 
74L, 51L, 39L, 38L, 25L, 21L, 18L, 20L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 28L, 37L, 
49L, 46L, 31L, 43L, 45L, 39L, 31L, 47L, 65L, 81L, 83L, 61L, 65L, 
58L, 37L, 20L, 31L, 15L, 25L, 17L, 12L, 21L, 42L, 106L, 115L, 
134L, 127L, 93L, 107L, 97L, 88L, 94L, 74L, 74L, 66L, 65L, 69L, 
52L, 51L, 28L, 19L, 23L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 17L, 39L, 91L, 115L, 
104L, 95L, 65L, 79L, 67L, 73L, 64L, 64L, 68L, 70L, 53L, 64L, 
48L, 38L)), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(date = structure(c(17563, 
17564, 17565, 17566), class = "Date"), .rows = list(1:24, 25:48, 
    49:72, 73:96)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Which looks like this:

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   date [1]
  date       hour  offered answered
  <date>     <chr>   <int>    <int>
1 2018-02-01 00         30       30
2 2018-02-01 01         28       28
3 2018-02-01 02         15       15
4 2018-02-01 03         21       21
5 2018-02-01 04         11       11
6 2018-02-01 05         14       14
```

How can I spread out the `hour` column and preserve both the `offered` and `answered` values for each date?

I have tried using `tidyr::spread()` but either keep getting error messages or lots of `NA` values in the results.  Also, I notice that it expects a single `value`, which is confusing.

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

Having thought about the problem some more, I now realise that it would be easier to spread the date values and just keep either `actual` or `offered`.

I won't change the question as there are some helpful solutions posted that may assist others, but instead I will add to it.

Ultimately, something like this would be ideal:

[image]

Comment: What should the result look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `gather` and `spread` from `tidyr` -

```
df %>% 
  gather(key = variable, value = value, -date, -hour) %>% 
  spread(hour, value)

# A tibble: 8 x 26
  date       variable  `00`  `01`  `02`  `03`  `04`  `05`  `06`  `07`  `08`  `09`  `10`  `11`  `12`  `13`  `14`  `15`  `16`
  <date>     <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 2018-02-01 answered    30    28    15    21    11    14    18    35    42    36    37    38    54    45    37    51    40
2 2018-02-01 offered     30    28    15    21    11    14    18    35    42    36    37    38    54    45    37    52    40
3 2018-02-02 answered    25    21    18    20     7    14    14    28    37    49    46    31    43    45    39    31    47
4 2018-02-02 offered     25    21    18    20     7    14    14    28    37    50    46    31    45    45    39    31    48
5 2018-02-03 answered    20    31    15    25    17    12    21    42   106   115   134   127    93   107    97    88    94
6 2018-02-03 offered     20    31    15    26    18    12    21    42   107   118   138   137    93   109   102    91   102
7 2018-02-04 answered    28    19    23    12    16    12    17    39    91   115   104    95    65    79    67    73    64
8 2018-02-04 offered     28    19    23    12    16    12    18    39    96   119   111    95    65    81    67    76    64
# ... with 7 more variables: `17` <int>, `18` <int>, `19` <int>, `20` <int>, `21` <int>, `22` <int>, `23` <int>
```

I'd suggest changing the hour values to character (ex. h00) before spreading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how wide you want the output to be, but here are two options with data.table `melt` and `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

dcast(melt(df, c('date', 'hour')), date + variable ~ paste0('hour_', hour))
# 
#          date variable hour_00 hour_01 hour_02 hour_03 hour_04 hour_05 hour_06 hour_07
# 1: 2018-02-01  offered      30      28      15      21      11      14      18      35
# 2: 2018-02-01 answered      30      28      15      21      11      14      18      35
# 3: 2018-02-02  offered      25      21      18      20       7      14      14      28
# 4: 2018-02-02 answered      25      21      18      20       7      14      14      28
# 5: 2018-02-03  offered      20      31      15      26      18      12      21      42
# 6: 2018-02-03 answered      20      31      15      25      17      12      21      42
# 7: 2018-02-04  offered      28      19      23      12      16      12      18      39
# 8: 2018-02-04 answered      28      19      23      12      16      12      17      39
#    hour_08 hour_09 hour_10 hour_11 hour_12 hour_13 hour_14 hour_15 hour_16 hour_17
# 1:      42      36      37      38      54      45      37      52      40      66
# 2:      42      36      37      38      54      45      37      51      40      66
# 3:      37      50      46      31      45      45      39      31      48      69
# 4:      37      49      46      31      43      45      39      31      47      65
# 5:     107     118     138     137      93     109     102      91     102      76
# 6:     106     115     134     127      93     107      97      88      94      74
# 7:      96     119     111      95      65      81      67      76      64      64
# 8:      91     115     104      95      65      79      67      73      64      64
#    hour_18 hour_19 hour_20 hour_21 hour_22 hour_23
# 1:      84      69      75      51      39      38
# 2:      83      68      74      51      39      38
# 3:      91     117      74      66      60      37
# 4:      81      83      61      65      58      37
# 5:      76      70      68      74      55      54
# 6:      74      66      65      69      52      51
# 7:      68      71      54      65      51      41
# 8:      68      70      53      64      48      38
```

Or if you want a separate column for offered and answered

```
dcast(df, date ~ hour, value.var = c('offered', 'answered'))

#          date offered_00 offered_01 offered_02 offered_03 offered_04 offered_05
# 1: 2018-02-01         30         28         15         21         11         14
# 2: 2018-02-02         25         21         18         20          7         14
# 3: 2018-02-03         20         31         15         26         18         12
# 4: 2018-02-04         28         19         23         12         16         12
#    offered_06 offered_07 offered_08 offered_09 offered_10 offered_11 offered_12
# 1:         18         35         42         36         37         38         54
# 2:         14         28         37         50         46         31         45
# 3:         21         42        107        118        138        137         93
# 4:         18         39         96        119        111         95         65
#    offered_13 offered_14 offered_15 offered_16 offered_17 offered_18 offered_19
# 1:         45         37         52         40         66         84         69
# 2:         45         39         31         48         69         91        117
# 3:        109        102         91        102         76         76         70
# 4:         81         67         76         64         64         68         71
#    offered_20 offered_21 offered_22 offered_23 answered_00 answered_01 answered_02
# 1:         75         51         39         38          30          28          15
# 2:         74         66         60         37          25          21          18
# 3:         68         74         55         54          20          31          15
# 4:         54         65         51         41          28          19          23
#    answered_03 answered_04 answered_05 answered_06 answered_07 answered_08 answered_09
# 1:          21          11          14          18          35          42          36
# 2:          20           7          14          14          28          37          49
# 3:          25          17          12          21          42         106         115
# 4:          12          16          12          17          39          91         115
#    answered_10 answered_11 answered_12 answered_13 answered_14 answered_15 answered_16
# 1:          37          38          54          45          37          51          40
# 2:          46          31          43          45          39          31          47
# 3:         134         127          93         107          97          88          94
# 4:         104          95          65          79          67          73          64
#    answered_17 answered_18 answered_19 answered_20 answered_21 answered_22 answered_23
# 1:          66          83          68          74          51          39          38
# 2:          65          81          83          61          65          58          37
# 3:          74          74          66          65          69          52          51
# 4:          64          68          70          53          64          48          38
```