# How can I spread the dates in this data frame?

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I need to spread the date value of a data frame (long to wide) but am having trouble achieving this because there are two variables that I need.

A solution I thought of might be to create two separate data frames, one for each variable, with the hourly values listed in the rows and dates listed in the columns.

[I asked this question differently initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923514/how-can-i-spread-a-data-frame-from-long-to-wide-and-preserve-two-fields-data), but have since thought of a better way to pose it; as such, I shan't be deleting it but rather posting my revised requirements as the original question may help others.

My data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 
17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 
17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 17563, 
17563, 17563, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 
17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 
17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17564, 17565, 
17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 
17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 
17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17565, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 
17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 
17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 17566, 
17566, 17566), class = "Date"), hour = c("00", "01", "02", "03", 
"04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "00", "01", 
"02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "23", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
"09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23"), offered = c(30L, 28L, 15L, 21L, 11L, 
14L, 18L, 35L, 42L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 54L, 45L, 37L, 52L, 40L, 66L, 
84L, 69L, 75L, 51L, 39L, 38L, 25L, 21L, 18L, 20L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 
28L, 37L, 50L, 46L, 31L, 45L, 45L, 39L, 31L, 48L, 69L, 91L, 117L, 
74L, 66L, 60L, 37L, 20L, 31L, 15L, 26L, 18L, 12L, 21L, 42L, 107L, 
118L, 138L, 137L, 93L, 109L, 102L, 91L, 102L, 76L, 76L, 70L, 
68L, 74L, 55L, 54L, 28L, 19L, 23L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 18L, 39L, 96L, 
119L, 111L, 95L, 65L, 81L, 67L, 76L, 64L, 64L, 68L, 71L, 54L, 
65L, 51L, 41L), answered = c(30L, 28L, 15L, 21L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 
35L, 42L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 54L, 45L, 37L, 51L, 40L, 66L, 83L, 68L, 
74L, 51L, 39L, 38L, 25L, 21L, 18L, 20L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 28L, 37L, 
49L, 46L, 31L, 43L, 45L, 39L, 31L, 47L, 65L, 81L, 83L, 61L, 65L, 
58L, 37L, 20L, 31L, 15L, 25L, 17L, 12L, 21L, 42L, 106L, 115L, 
134L, 127L, 93L, 107L, 97L, 88L, 94L, 74L, 74L, 66L, 65L, 69L, 
52L, 51L, 28L, 19L, 23L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 17L, 39L, 91L, 115L, 
104L, 95L, 65L, 79L, 67L, 73L, 64L, 64L, 68L, 70L, 53L, 64L, 
48L, 38L)), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(date = structure(c(17563, 
17564, 17565, 17566), class = "Date"), .rows = list(1:24, 25:48, 
    49:72, 73:96)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Which looks like this:

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   date [1]
  date       hour  offered answered
  <date>     <chr>   <int>    <int>
1 2018-02-01 00         30       30
2 2018-02-01 01         28       28
3 2018-02-01 02         15       15
4 2018-02-01 03         21       21
5 2018-02-01 04         11       11
6 2018-02-01 05         14       14
```

This is how I would like the output to look (one for `offered`, one for `answered`):

[image]

I'm pretty sure that I can achieve this with `tidyr::spread()` but haven't been able to get it to look like the image above.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it in two parts, `select` the required columns and `spread` them to wide format and then change the `hour` column by pasting current `hour` value with the next `hour` value.

For `offered`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(date, hour, offered) %>%
  spread(date, offered) %>%
  mutate(hour = paste(hour, lead(hour, default = first(hour)), sep = "-")) 


# A tibble: 24 x 5
#   hour  `2018-02-01` `2018-02-02` `2018-02-03` `2018-02-04`
#   <chr>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
# 1 00-01           30           25           20           28
# 2 01-02           28           21           31           19
# 3 02-03           15           18           15           23
# 4 03-04           21           20           26           12
# 5 04-05           11            7           18           16
# 6 05-06           14           14           12           12
# 7 06-07           18           14           21           18
# 8 07-08           35           28           42           39
# 9 08-09           42           37          107           96
#10 09-10           36           50          118          119
# … with 14 more rows
```

and for `answered`

```
df %>%
  select(date, hour, answered) %>%
  spread(date, answered) %>%
  mutate(hour = paste(hour, lead(hour, default = first(hour)), sep = "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` as `spread` is getting deprecated

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  select(-answered) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = offered) %>% 
  mutate(hour = str_c(hour, lead(hour, default = first(hour)), sep="_"))
# A tibble: 24 x 5
#   hour  `2018-02-01` `2018-02-02` `2018-02-03` `2018-02-04`
#   <chr>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
# 1 00_01           30           25           20           28
# 2 01_02           28           21           31           19
# 3 02_03           15           18           15           23
# 4 03_04           21           20           26           12
# 5 04_05           11            7           18           16
# 6 05_06           14           14           12           12
# 7 06_07           18           14           21           18
# 8 07_08           35           28           42           39
# 9 08_09           42           37          107           96
#10 09_10           36           50          118          119
# … with 14 more rows
```